# Python ctypes and not enough arguments (4 bytes missing)

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

The function i'm trying to call is:

```
void FormatError (HRESULT hrError,PCHAR pszText);
```

from a custom dll using windll.

```
c_p = c_char_p()
windll.thedll.FormatError(errcode, c_p)
```

Results in:

```
ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing)
```

Using cdll instead increases the bytes missing counter to 12. errcode above is the errercode returned from another function out of the same dll.  How do I get the call right?

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you'll get more descriptive errors if you properly set up the [`argtypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) and the [`restype`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types).

Try doing it this way:

```
windll.thedll.FormatError.argtypes = [ctypes.HRESULT, ctypes.c_char_p]
windll.thedll.FormatError.restype  = None
```

There's also a very good chance you are using the wrong calling convention -- check out [the Calling Functions section](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions) and [the Loading Libraries section](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries) for details on how to use a different calling convention.

Comment: I tried setting argtypes and restype, without luck
as I can access other functions without problems using windll I think windll should work here too

Comment: Okay, but the Calling Functions section *exactly* shows the same error as you had above, saying `4 bytes missing`.  You're able to call other functions in that *same* DLL with `windll`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the [ctypes.HRESULT](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.HRESULT)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you want to use FormatError as provided by ctypes

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.FormatError

> ctypes.FormatError([code])
>
> Windows only: Returns a textual description of the error code. If
>   no error code is specified, the last error code is used by calling
>   the Windows api function GetLastError.

Comment: The DLL provides it's own FormatError Function and I want to use it.