# Python 32bit on Windows 64bit Ctypes module error

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ctypes, windows64

in both python 3.4.3 and 2.7.9 when I try to call any function from kernel library.

from 32bit version of python on 64bit windows, an error message is printed:

```
from ctypes import *
path=create_string_buffer(256) 
rs=cdll.Kernel32.GetModuleFileNameA(0,path,256)
print (path)
```

**the error is as following :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test-ctypes.py", line 3, in <module>
      ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (12 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python ctypes and not enough arguments (4 bytes missing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458813/python-ctypes-and-not-enough-arguments-4-bytes-missing)

Comment: even if I defined the function argtypes and restype the problem appears..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception message tells you the answer:

ValueError: Procedure called with *not enough arguments* (12 bytes missing) or *wrong calling convention*

The number of arguments is right, so it must be the other: You are using the wrong calling convention. The calling convention is the way the compiler maps the three arguments in C into a way to store the actual values in memory when calling the function (among a few other things). On the [MSDN documentation for GetModuleFileA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you find the following signature

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileName(
  _In_opt_ HMODULE hModule,
  _Out_    LPTSTR  lpFilename,
  _In_     DWORD   nSize
);
```

The `WINAPI` tells the compiler to use the `stdcall` calling convention. Your ctypes code uses `cdll` which on the other hand assumes `cdecl` calling convetion. The solution is simple: change `cdll` to `windll`:

```
from ctypes import *
path=create_string_buffer(256) 
rs=windll.Kernel32.GetModuleFileNameA(0,path,256)
print (path)
```

Compare with the [ctypes documentation for accessing .dll's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries), where `kernel32` is explicitely shown to use `windll`.

Comment: what I was really searching for is how to explicitly use specific callingcanvention

Comment: @user3406177, it's more idiomatic to use `None` when passing a `NULL` pointer value. Also, if you don't define its `restype` and `argtypes`, `GetModuleFileNameA` will not work properly on 64-bit Windows. Use the Windows types defined in `ctypes.wintypes`. Also, please use `kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32')` if you're creating a library.